# How to hide/show a specific component on react

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that shows a couple  Charts and I want to create a button for each of them that shows or hides the charts. I had found how to hide and show but it does't work for me because it hides or show all the Charts, any help will be well received.

By the way I'm totally new to react so my apologies if I don't express myself well.

My code so far:

```js
export default class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);

        this.handleShow = this.handleShow.bind(this);
        this.handleHide = this.handleHide.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            show: false,
            isHidden: true,

        };
    }




    toggle() {
        this.setState({
            isHidden: !this.state.isHidden,
        });
    }




    render() {

        let shown = {
            display: this.state.isHidden  ? "inline-block" : "none"
        };

        let hidden = {
            display: this.state.isHidden ? "none" : "inline-block"
        };

        return (
            <div className="Home">

                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-12">
                        <div className="card">
                            <div className="card-header">
                                <h4 className="card-title">Gráficos</h4>

                                <div className="viewOptions">

                                    <button className="btn bg-info"
                                    ID="prueba">ODC'S
                                    onClick={this.toggle.bind(this)}
                                        <FontAwesome name="eye"/>
                                    </button>
                                    <button 
                                    onClick={this.toggle.bind(this)}
                                    className="btn bg-info">ODI'S  <FontAwesome name="eye"/></button>
                                    <button className="btn bg-info">EGRESOS  <FontAwesome name="eye"/></button>
                                    <button className="btn bg-info">INGRESOS  <FontAwesome name="eye"/></button>
                                    <button className="btn bg-info">ESPACIOS RENTADOS  <FontAwesome name="eye"/></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>



                            {/*ODC'S COLOCADAS*/}

                            <Echart 1
                            style={show} >
                            
                            <Echart 2
                            style ={show}>
                            
                            <Echart ...>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Gosh, can you shorten the code you provide a bit? This is quite a lot to go through.

Comment: Your show/hide technique is totally ok but split that huge amount of html into subcomponents and toggle visibility for those components.

Answer (score 1):

JanneP's logic on comment is right, but if you want to keep the logic on the container, then you would need to have some sort of key or index for each item.

So the button can look something like this:

```
<button onClick={ () => {
        // keep the state
        let shown = [ ...this.state.shown ];
        // revert the stored boolean to toggle
        shown.chart1 = !shown.chart1
        this.setState({ shown });
    }
} />
```

And the chart could be:

```
// If not familiar with the ternary: that is just shorthand if statement
<Chart style={ this.state.shown.chart1 ? { display: 'inline-block' } : { display: 'none' } } />
```

Comment: it helps me a lot thank u, the only drawback of which I could realized its that in  the moment I click on any button it shows the Chart but also hide the rest of them :c

Comment: @KarenSamnao Hmm, this logic should not. Can you paste your full code to bin or do you have a pen for this?

Comment: @KarenSamano Well, for me it looks like the code is not very well formatted, so it is a bit hard to follow. But at least one problem there is: you are setting shown.ODI but later checking shown.ODC...