# How can I hide/view components in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I have several components. What I want to do is when I render component " Cart " I want to disable " App" from rendering.

here is my index.js

```
 ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={store}>
<HashRouter>
  <App>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/categories" component={Categories} />
      <Route path="/category/:categId" component={Products} />
      <Route path="/product/:productId" component={Product} />
      <Route path="/cart" component={Cart} />
    </Switch>
  </App>
</HashRouter>
 </Provider>
 , document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

I thought of accessing the url everytime in App component and whenever the path equals to " cart " I return null but it didn't work with me.

Comment: Take a look in 'Prevent component from rendering' in React's oficial docs: [https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide/show a specific component on react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50805219/how-to-hide-show-a-specific-component-on-react)

Answer (score 1):

Use a boolean variable and a ternary statement like this super simplified example:

```
const isCart = cartShowing === true

return isCart
    ? <Cart/>
    : <App />
```

Comment: I will try it now

Answer (score 0):

I'm affraid that it isn't a simple question about conditional rendering.

SHORT: Don't think this way.

LONGER: If you need to render `Cart` with different layout then do it inside `Cart`. As one of top level components/containers it can render common (with other routes) `<PageLayout />` and `<CartList />` inside.

`App` is a logical glue/structural part, doesn't intended to contain any visual elements.

Comment: Although my answer answers the question directly, I do agree that OP should rather rethink his approach by using top level containers for shop(?) vs. cart.